# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000008346beb8

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I get the following crash log from Crashlytics for my app. My code do not call msgpack_zone_free or msgpack parse method at all and so I'm confused how that happened. I'm unable to reproduce this crash myself so I'm left to analyze the issue from the crash report itself. Any pointers to what I need to check will be very helpful.

This is not a case of low memory as I see free memory from Crashlytics.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000192953bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001820d5228 CFRelease + 524
2  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001821e62ac -[__NSArrayM removeAllObjects] + 284
3  MyApp                          0x00000001004a69e0 msgpack_zone_free
4  MyApp                          0x00000001004a4afc msgpack_zone_free
5  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018219cae4 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
6  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001820db220 _CFXNotificationPost + 2060
7  Foundation                     0x0000000182fdac60 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
8  UIKit                          0x0000000186c32e98 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDectivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 1132
9  UIKit                          0x0000000186c3b370 __88-[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 92
10 UIKit                          0x0000000186c3b2f8 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 380
11 UIKit                          0x0000000186c2ec2c -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 512
12 FrontBoardServices             0x000000018a45d62c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 28
13 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001821aea28 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
14 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001821adb30 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
15 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001821ac154 __CFRunLoopRun + 1756
16 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001820d90a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
17 GraphicsServices               0x000000018b2735a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
18 UIKit                          0x0000000186a0aaa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
19 MyApp                          0x00000001000cce40 main (main.m:16)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000192faea08 start + 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems one of your notification observer is deallocated/expired.

Comment: It seemed so to me but I use a singleton object to observer for notifications and that should never get released as long as the app runs.  Any chance this could happen due to memory leaks in msgpack etc?

Comment: have you tried atos and dwarfdump on dSym of this particular build? Maybe you should look up for 0x00000001004a69e0 and 0x00000001004a4afc addresses( for myApp). Maybe you will get more accurate information where it does crash.

Comment: @NickCatib I developed some SDK (being given out as a static/fake framework) which is being used by a client developer and the crash is on his application. So I guess I have to ask him for the dsym file. Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: Well, if you pushed your build to crashalitycs you could get the dsym file from .ipa :)